# FMOD play multiple sounds at same time

Tags: c++, fmod

I needed to play multiple sounds simultaneously, so I tried to initialize the `FMOD::System` with many channels, but after playing some files it does nothing. When I sleep 1 second, the sound stops with `count` about 35, with sleep 0.1 second the last `count` is about 100.

```
int count = 1;

FMOD::System *system = NULL;
FMOD::System_Create(&system);
system->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

while(true)
{
    FMOD::Sound *sound = NULL;
    system->createSound("test.wav", FMOD_DEFAULT, FMOD_DEFAULT ,&sound);

    FMOD::Channel *channel = NULL;
    FMOD_RESULT result = system->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, sound, false, &channel);

    cout << "count: " << count << ", " << result;
    count++;
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = 1;
    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
}
```

When I also write this part into the while loop I also recognized, that the pointer to the `FMOD::System` changes at the very beginning and remains the same after some seconds.

```
FMOD::System *system = NULL;
FMOD::System_Create(&system);
system->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);
```

What have I done wrong? It even doesn't use the 100 channels!
What can I do to play many sounds synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I forgot to `system->update()`.
The code code should look like this:

```
int count = 1;

FMOD::System *system = NULL;
FMOD::System_Create(&system);
system->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

while(true)
{
    FMOD::Sound *sound = NULL;
    system->createSound("test.wav", FMOD_DEFAULT, FMOD_DEFAULT ,&sound);

    FMOD::Channel *channel = NULL;
    FMOD_RESULT result = system->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, sound, false, &channel);

    system->update(); // very important!!!

    cout << "count: " << count << ", " << result;

    count++;

    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = 1;
    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
}
```